# Save realm result in a variable and write in realm without changing the variable

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, realm

I am saving realm result in a variable in the hope to use it for different purpose. After i update it in Realm the variable in which i stored the original result also gets updated. I want to keep the variable in which I get original realm results unaltered.

Below i save the variable

```
componentDidMount(){
this.showFromRealm();
this.oldOpts = Array.from(Realm.objects('Device')[0].ns);
```

}

This is how i update in realm

```
  if(device){
  Realm.write(() => {
    device.ns.forEach((ns)=>{
      if(ns.idx == selectedType){
        ns.opt.forEach((opt)=>{
          if(opt.idx == selectedOpt.idx) opt.val = !selectedOpt.val;
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

This is how i re-write the variable in realm.

```
 Realm.write(() => {
    device.ns = this.oldOpts;
  });
```

Any insight would be helpful.
I want to write the original result again in realm so as to make it appear as initial.

Comment: RealmObjects are live, auto-updating. You can use `Realm.copyFromRealm` to detach the object from Realm, this will stop updating it.
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#auto-updating-objects

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am using realm in react native and not java though. @NabilHachicha

Comment: Maybe https://realm.io/docs/javascript/1.10.0/api/Realm.Results.html#snapshot is what you are looking for.

Comment: In documentation it says that it is not a deep snapshot. this is from the link you gave -> " This is not a deep snapshot, meaning the objects contained in this snapshot will continue to update as changes are made to them."
Please correct me if i am understanding it incorrectly.